# Why do I keep getting "Exception: Service invoked too many times in a short time: groups read. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls."?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups, google-groups-api

I just ran a sample code from Apps Script tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getGroups()

(I have commented out the loop part to make the problem clear.)

```
function listGroupMembers() {
  var GROUP_EMAIL = "a-group@in.mydomain";
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
  Utilities.sleep(10000);

  var childGroups = group.getGroups();
  console.log("Group " + GROUP_EMAIL + " has " + childGroup.length + " groups:");

  /* comment out the loop to make the problem clear.
  for (var i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    console.log(childGroup.getEmail());
  }
  */

}
```

But I keep getting the following exception:

```
Exception: Service invoked too many times in a short time: groups read. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls. 
listGroupMembers    @ test.gs:6
```

Even if I run a script for the first time in the last 24 hours, I get this exception. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It must be the limitation of `getGroups()`.

I tested a group with changing the number of child groups. Below is the result.

- Num of Group: 1 to 7: Always success.
- Num of Group: 8: Sometimes fail.
- Num of Group: 9: Sometimes success.
- Num of Group: 10: Always fail.

Looks like we can use `getGroups()` only when the number child groups is 7 or less.

Answer (score 0):

#### Possible Issues:

- There is a lot of calls to your `getEmail()`. Even if the function was executed once, consecutive `childGroup.getEmail()` was called many times inside the loop in a short duration of time going past the quota.
- Groups read shows a limit of 2000/10000 (depending on your account) per day. If yours go beyond that limit, then it reached the quota. If not, then maybe it reached the per minute/hour quota (haven't found the documentation how many is it per minute/hour)

[image: groups]

#### Possible steps you could take:

- Place your `sleep` function inside the loop so it pauses every loop, thus reducing the calls done per minute/hour. See if that alleviates the problem.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    console.log(childGroup.getEmail());
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
```

- If it didn't, check the length of your `childGroups`. If that goes beyond the limit, try to limit your loop into 1950/9950 if it fixes the problem. If that fixes it, then it is confirmed that your function fails because of the quota being reached.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 1950; i++) { // or 9950, depending on the account
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    console.log(childGroup.getEmail());
    Utilities.sleep(10000);
  }
```

#### Reference:

- [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed reply. I appreciate it. Well, actually the exception is raised at `  var childGroups = group.getGroups();`

To make it clear, I commented out `childGroup.getEmail()` part. (I have updated the question.) but I still get the same exception.

Comment: In short, only `group.getGroups()` causes the exception.

Comment: Hi @NaokiIshihara, how long was the function running before it failed?

Comment: It's fairly new and weird to me that a single command causes this issue. I have looked it up and somehow wasn't able to find similar issues. @NaokiIshihara

Comment: It takes a few seconds until I get the exception after I run. Yes, it is really weird and that's why I am asking here. Is there anything I can do for further investigation?

Comment: It would be best if you can try it under a different account under the same domain/organization? Would that be possible? @NaokiIshihara

Comment: I tried with other group and I got another error: `Error 
ReferenceError: childGroup is not defined` even though the group has a child group. 
I will also try to use another account to run the script.

Comment: I had my colleague run the same script and he got the same result. Also I found some interesting result with other group: 
* group-g@ (has  10 child groups): always get the exception except once.  
* group-t@ (has 1 child group): always get the successful output. 
* group-w@ (has 1 child group): always get the successful output. 
getGroups() for a group that has 10 child groups causes the error?

Comment: If that's the case, then maybe, `getGroups` is using a background process (let's assume `getGroup` or something like that) which is being called everytime it has a child. so it may be is limited to how much group is there. You can try testing it further on other groups as well having the number of child is the variable. If our assumption was true, then it might be a limitation to what the method is able to do.

Comment: I tested a group changing the number of child group. # of Group 1 to 7: Always success. # of Group 8: Sometimes fail. # of Group 9: Sometimes success. # of Group 10: Always fail. 
Looks like you are right. `getGroups()` has the limitation. We can use it only when the number child groups is 7 or less. It is not convenient though. 
Is there anyway to report this bug?

Comment: Have it posted in this one. @NaokiIshihara, https://issuetracker.google.com